# Homotopy groups of Connected sum of Manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory

**Q_1)** Let $n\geq 3$, and $M, N$ be path-connected (but not necessary simply connected) n-manifolds. Is there any result about how to compute the nth homotopy group of the connected sum $M\# N$ from knowing the homotopy groups of $M, N$ up to dimension $n$.

**Q_2)** In particular, I am interested to know whether such a methods known when $M$ and $N$ are non-trivial ($\pi_1(N), \pi_1(M)\neq 0$) homology n-spheres? For example, is there a non-trivial n-homology sphere $M$ such that $\pi_n(M\# M)$ is finite?

**Comment:** Computing $\pi_1(M\# N)$ can be done via the Van-Kampen Theorem and also $\pi_2(M\# N)$ is also manageable as it is equal to the second homology group of its universal cover.

Comment: This can be done if $M,N$ are highly connected by means of a Blaker-Massey sequence. In general it's a difficult problem, and it'll probably be more fruitful to use geometric methods e.g. to concretely identify the universal covering.

Comment: See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93282/homotopy-groups-of-connected-sums); I am sure Ronnie Brown gave similar answers elsewhere at Math Stack Exchange.